# Use case_when and startsWith to selectively mutate by row

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to create a new column based on another, using `case_when` to give different outputs based on the value of each row.

I start with `df <- data.frame(a=c("abc", "123", "abc", "123"))`

And want to generate a new column `b` like so

```
#>     a      b
#> 1 abc letter
#> 2 123 number
#> 3 abc letter
#> 4 123 number
```

I've tried `df %>% mutate(b = case_when(startsWith(a, "a") ~ "letter", startsWith(a, "1") ~ "number"))` but it only gives an error. Can someone show me how to get different values for column b based on the first letter of the row in column a?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to `?startsWith`

> x -vector of character string whose “starts” are considered.

So, `startsWith` expects the class to be `character` and here it is `factor` class.  Converting it to `character` class would solve the issue

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
      mutate(b = case_when(startsWith(as.character(a), "a") ~ "letter",
                 TRUE ~ "number"))
#    a      b
#1 abc letter
#2 123 number
#3 abc letter
#4 123 number
```

The default behavior of `data.frame` would be `stringsAsFactors  = TRUE`.  If we specify `stringsAsFactors = FALSE`, the 'a' column will be `character` class

---

Another option is `str_detect` to create a logical expression by checking if the character from the start (`^`) of the string is a digit (`[0-9]`)

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
    mutate(b = c("letter", "number")[1+str_detect(a, "^[0-9]")])
#    a      b
#1 abc letter
#2 123 number
#3 abc letter
# 123 number
```

Comment: Ah! stringsAsFactors strikes again! Thanks for the help.

Answer (score -1):

You can just use `if_else()` since there's only two cases here. A regex seems more appropriate, given the test you're trying to run; the key is that `^` specifies the start of the string, and `[:alpha:]` matches alphabetical letters, case-insensitive.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(a=c("abc", "123", "abc", "123"))

df %>% mutate(
  b = a %>% str_detect("^[:alpha:]") %>% if_else("letter", "number")
)
#>     a      b
#> 1 abc letter
#> 2 123 number
#> 3 abc letter
#> 4 123 number
```

<sup>Created on 2019-09-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

As @akrun pointed out, there is an issue here with factors vs. characters - are you sure this is an appropriate example for your use case, i.e. your real data is in factors? Luckily, though, `str_detect()` works just as well either way.

Comment: I tried to present a minimally representative example. My real data has 5 cases.

Comment: @pgcudahy But is it coded as factors, or character strings? Because it's factor in the example, but only because that's the default behavior of `data.frame()`, so I'm not sure if it was intended.